# Globbing in C, how to exclude files

Tags: c, glob

I've read http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob and it seems that glob will do disk access, even though I don't want it to.

Is there a C glob function to compare a string with a glob pattern and tell me if it matches?  i.e. no disk access.

If not, how can I use glob to *exclude* files when recursively (depth first) traversing a filesystem?

```
while((entry = readdir(dp))) {
    // need to continue to next iteration of loop, here, if entry->d_name matches glob pattern

    // do stuff and recurse
}
```

Comment: See the `fnmatch` function listed in the See Also section of the page you linked.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thanks, just what I was looking for.  If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [fnmatch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch) function. It compares a filename/path against a given pattern.